# Supporing Arabic in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am planning to write a twitter app for Windows phone 7 with supporting Arabic, RTL with complex scripting, and with Arabic keyboard layout like the one in this [app](http://wp7.apphab.com/arabic-sms-by-sofisoft/) as this langauge is not supported by WP7.

I tried looking for a resources to help with this porcess but couldnt find any.

So does anyone have an idea on how the complex scripting can be rendered in WP7 through apps?

regards,

Answer (score 0):

I saw a demo on a Windows Phone lately. Arabic text is shown normally in internet explorer and even SMS! But user can not write Arabic in the current moment as the Windows Phone 7 now is not supporting it. But People in Redmond promised it will be available in next language package updates! May be you should let Arabic supporting feature for the next version of your application.

About the app you pointed as example, I believe they have made their own custom keyboard! So you might contact the company developed the application and ask them for keyboard if it is available as 3rd party component.